# Rosalind: Overlap Graphs in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, rosalind

How to solve the Overlap Graphs problem on Rosalind?

http://rosalind.info/problems/grph/

Answer (score 0):

Proposal is to define following type :

```
type rosalind = {name : string; dna: string; kprefix: string; ksuffix: string}
```

The parse your db to build a list of Rosalind ; using String.sub to compute kprefix & ksuffix ; that would lead to a list rosa_list.

Then iter on rosalist

```
list.iter (fun y -> List.iter (fun x -> if x.ksuffix = y.prefix then print_useful_info ) rosa_list) rosa_list
```